# WSL run linux from windows without spawning a cmd-window

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL bash running in a cmd. I don't use it for anything, it just hangs there to keep the WSL system alive.

When I start X applications:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage hello &"
```

I get this result:

[image]

I can close down the command window without any problems, but it's rather annoying.

How can run commands without getting this cmd window every time?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a **simpler solution**, which, however, requires a **[WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)-based helper script**, `runHidden.vbs` (see bottom section):

```
wscript .\runHidden.vbs bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage 'hello, world'"
```

To apply @davv's own launch-in-background technique to avoid creating a new `bash` instance every time:

***One-time* action** (e.g., at boot time): launch a hidden, stay-open `bash` window. This spawns *2* `bash` processes: the *Windows* `bash.exe` process that owns the console window, and the WSL `bash` process (owned by the WSL `init` singleton), which is then available for servicing *background commands*.

```
wscript .\runHidden.vbs bash # hidden helper instance for servicing background commands
```

***For every X Window-launching command***: Terminate each command with `&` to have it be run by the hidden WSL `bash` instance *asynchronously*, without keeping the *invoking* `bash` instance alive:

```
wscript .\runHidden.vbs bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage 'hello, world' &"
```

---

#### `runHidden.vbs` source code:

```vb
' Simple command-line help.
select case WScript.Arguments(0)
case "-?", "/?", "-h", "--help"
  WScript.echo "Usage: runHidden executable [...]" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Runs the specified command hidden (without a visible window)."
  WScript.Quit(0)
end select

' Separate the arguments into the executable name
' and a single string containing all arguments.
exe = WScript.Arguments(0)
sep = ""
for i = 1 to WScript.Arguments.Count -1
  ' Enclose arguments in "..." to preserve their original partitioning, if necessary.
  if Instr(WScript.Arguments(i), " ") > 0 then
    args = args & sep & """" & WScript.Arguments(i) & """"
  else
    args = args & sep & WScript.Arguments(i)
  end if
  sep = " "
next

' Execute the command with its window *hidden* (0)
WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute exe, args, "", "open", 0
```

Even when launched from a GUI app (such as via the `Run` dialog invoked with <kbd>Win+R</kbd>), this will not show a console window.

**If your system is configured to execute `.vbs` scripts with `wscript.exe` by default** (`wscript //h:wscript /s`, which, I think, is the default configuration), **you can invoke `runHidden.vbs` directly, and if you put it in your `%PATH%`, by filename (root) only: `runHidden ...`**.

Note that use of the script is not limited to *console* applications: even GUI applications can be run hidden with it.

Answer (score 4):

There's another simple solution, it requires an external executable though. It has no dependencies and was recommended by [aseering on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/841#issuecomment-270375321).

> you can launch bash via run.exe: run.exe bash.exe -c "<whatever Linux command>". (run.exe is available here: http://www.straightrunning.com/projectrun/ , make sure you download the 64-bit version, the 32-bit version will not be able to find or run bash).

With `run` on the search PATH, you can just call

`run bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage hello"`

Comment: For this one, run.exe complains about not finding bash or bash.exe. Btw, bash.exe and run.exe are in the same ...\system32 directory. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you need the 64-bit version of run.exe (Edit was suggested by 
Sjoerd van Leent).

Answer (score 4):

There no longer is a need to have that command window pop up anymore with [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/blob/main/README.md) recently added to the mix.  You just can call bash using `wslg.exe`, like so (I use Ubuntu currently in WSL):

```bash
wslg ~ -d Ubuntu bash
```

This will create a BASH session that will just sit there without being seen.  Alternatively, you can do what I do and run a few services that stay running.  I created a script that checks for running services, and if it doesn't find them running, will run them.  Create the file in /usr/bin:

```bash
sudo touch /usr/bin/start-wsl-services

sudo nano /usr/bin/start-wsl-services
```

Paste the following into the file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check for and run System-wide DBus service.
SERVICE="dbus-daemon"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Check for and run CUPS Printing Service.
SERVICE="cupsd"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/cups start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Check for and start Freshclam CLAMAV Update service.
SERVICE="freshclam"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Check for and start SANED Scanner service.
SERVICE="saned"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/saned start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Check for and start screen-cleanup service.
SERVICE="screen-cleanup"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Check for and start Preload service.
SERVICE="preload"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
else
    sudo /etc/init.d/preload start
    pgrep -a "$SERVICE"
fi

# Prestart LibreOffice twice for faster loading.
#/usr/bin/libreoffice --terminate_after_init
#sleep 5
#/usr/bin/libreoffice --terminate_after_init

# Check for error, make sure all functions called and run, and pass the result on to calling process.
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Save and exit the file, and then make it executable:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/start-wsl-services
```

I then call this using a shortcut that runs a startup script at startup.  Or you can just run it manually.  The command I use in the startup script is:

```bash
C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe -d Ubuntu -- /usr/bin/start-wsl-services
```

The startup command script I use (named StartWSL.cmd) is as follows:

```bash
@echo off

echo Starting WSL Linux...

:RETRY

C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe -d Ubuntu -- /usr/bin/start-wsl-services

REM - C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c '/usr/bin/start-wsl-services'

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (GOTO RETRY)

REM - Allow time to see all results.
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >NUL

REM - Uncomment below line for troubleshooting.
REM - pause

exit 0
```

And that's how I now keep WSL running in the background on Windows 11, and similar to how I did it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

So I just made this workaround for now. I really hope that there's a better way than this, but here it goes:

In the command prompt that lives purely to keep WSL alive, I have this script running:

**wsl_run_server**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
nc -kl 127.0.0.1 15150 | sh
```

And then I have this command to execute commands in background:

**wsl_run_command**

```
if ! pidof -x bin/wsl_run_server; then
    echo wsl_run_server isnt running!
    exit 1
fi
echo \($@\) \& | nc localhost 15150
```

from windows I then call:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 ~/bin/wsl_run_command xmessage hello"
```

Comment: In your example above, should this be wsl_run_background_command instead of wsl_run_command xmessage?

Answer (score 0):

### run command background

`screen -dmS [name] [command]`

### example

`screen -dmS gui bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage hello"`

### create a shortcut on windows desktop(run in wsl)

`wslusc screen -dmS gui bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 xmessage hello"`

Answer (score 0):

Very later answer, but here's a python solution to run **wsl** commands without spawning a cmd-window :

```
import subprocess

cmd = sys.argv[1]
subprocess.getoutput(f'wsl {cmd}')
```

---

Usage:

`pythonw scriptname.py 'command here'`

---

Notes:

- **pythonw.exe** is an executable file that belongs to Python. This process runs graphical interface applications without launching a system shell.
- If **python.exe** is on your windows path, **pythonw.exe** should also be.
- Make sure to quote the wsl command