# How to run .cmd file commands hidden so that they don't show when they run

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I currently have a .cmd file that runs the following two commands on startup

```
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
PowerShell C:\Users\elias\Desktop\Script123.ps1 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
```

But when this runs on startup it shows the command prompt. I'm wondering if there's anyway to run this without showing the command prompt.

Thank You

Comment: Use -WindowStyle Hidden but window will be visible for second.

Comment: Open `cmd.exe`, type `powershell -?` <ENTER>

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: If you invoke a `.cmd` file directly, it invariably opens a console window, which happens _before_ `powershell` gets to run, so whatever the latter can do will be of no help here.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a `.cmd` file *directly* invariably opens a console window, so you need to invoke it via a *wrapper executable* that hides it:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41229169/45375) of mine contains a VBScript script that does just that; assuming you've saved it as `runHidden.vbs` in the current dir and that you want to invoke `some-batch-file.cmd` from the current dir:

```
wscript .\runHidden.vbs cmd "/c .\some-batch-file.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"` in the beginning of the code.

This command can minimize all windows.

I hope this can be helpful, if you have any other questions, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper with VBScript:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /c blah.cmd", 0, False
```

Then change the startup item to

```
wscript.exe wrapper.vbs
```